# chat.js:89 Uncaught ReferenceError: bind is not defined(…) In React js

Tags: ajax, reactjs

Hi I am a beginner in react js and making a project while running my code I have an error in the console

> chat.js:89 Uncaught ReferenceError: bind is not defined(…)

I am unable to find the mistake kindly help me.

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {data: []}
    }
  loadCommentsFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/get-latest-comments.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success(data) {
        bind(this.setState({data: data}))
      },
      error(xhr, status, err) {
        bind(console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString()))
      }
    });
  }

  handleCommentSubmit(comment) {
    // TODO: submit to the server and refresh the list
        var comments = this.state.data;
        var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
        this.setState({data: newComments});
        $.ajax({
          url: 'api/save-comment.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          data: comment,
          success(data) {
            bind(this.setState({data: data}))
          },
          error(xhr, status, err) {
            bind(console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString()))
          }
        });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">

        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
        <div className="page-header">
            <h1>Comments</h1>
        </div>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Old index.php's scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
```

New index.php's scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using `bind()` is wrong. You need to bind the `success` and `error` function in ajax to the correct context and not the data inside the function. Use bind as

```
success: function(data) {
    this.setState({data: data})
}.bind(this),
```

**Code:**

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {data: []}
    }
  loadCommentsFromServer = () => {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/get-latest-comments.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data})
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString())
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  handleCommentSubmit = (comment) => {
    // TODO: submit to the server and refresh the list
        var comments = this.state.data;
        var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
        this.setState({data: newComments});
        $.ajax({
          url: 'api/save-comment.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          data: comment,
          success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data})
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString())
          }.bind(this)
        });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">

        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
        <div className="page-header">
            <h1>Comments</h1>
        </div>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help I have run this code but on ` }.bind(this), ` an error in the console 
Unexpected token (89:6)(…)

Comment: Earlier, I added old scripts it worked fine but now I have updated scripts with new updated files these errors occurs...
I have edited my question to show you old and new scrips, kindly look at them and let me know what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: What I can suggest you to try is to specify the success function like `success: function() {}` and see if it works. Try the updated code

Comment: I have made changes acording to your instructions now it is displaying error at same line `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function()`

Comment: Just saw, any non lifecycle function in react need explicit binding to access states and props. You can bind your functions with fat arrows. Try the update once more